# Is there any service serving a list of all the possible physical or not disabilities with unique identifiers?

Tags: database, saas

I'm looking to build an event management tool and want to give users the possibility to inquire disabilities.

I need a predictable input refering to an existing disability or handicap so the event organizers and the software could know about it.

In a wonderfull world, i'd like to use the id or label to redirect the organizer to an help notice and i want it internationalizable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my question was downvoted, is it something with stackoverflow rules or the queston itself ?

Anyway, i found i could start answering my question here:

https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/ICF